# Embed html from memory with images on disk in c++

Tags: html, c++, regex

I am trying to load html files from memory and show it. However I have following problem. I can easily show html files from resource or from local directory and change its content on the fly. My problem is, html files have some images. In order to show the images correctly, images and html file must be in same directory of course. If I load html from resource, html control looks resource directory(FindResource, LoadResource etc) to find the image. If I set a local file in application directory and load it it works but it creates one dummy file within the program directory. I have come up with couple of ideas for implementing this, and I hope you can give me some comments.

1. Load dummy html file from resource, add html on the fly and hook, FindResource, LoadResource etc from mshtml and give file name, file size, content
2. Use Regex filters to find src attribute and concatenate directory name with file:// protocol
3. Use html parser to traverse the DOM and change src attribute.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is one consistent thing on Stack Overflow it's that trying to parse the DOM with just a Regular Expression will get you yelled at.

However, I have an idea that uses a regular expression *to find a pattern in the html* and you can insert an element that might fix your problem.

What you can do (and I haven't done C++ in 20 years so I'm going to have to psuedo code this), is find the head tag and add a `base` element that specifies a base url for all images and anchors.

```
Regex regex = new Regex('</head>', RegexFlag.CaseInsensitve);
sHtml = regex.replace(sHtml, "<base href=\"http://www.base.com/" /></head>");
```

This assumes you always have a head tag and your head element is well formed.  You might have to check to see that the regex actually finds something first, and if it doesn't then do something similar with the start tag of the html element, and if you can't find that well... garbage in, garbage out.

And fart, a base element might actually already exist.  So you might want do a regex replace on that too: `<base[^>]*>`.  Just replace it with an empty string.

More about base element: http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-set-relative-urls-with-the-base-tag--cms-21399

... obviously a less sloppy solution is to use a DOM parser, but this should work in a pinch.

Comment: I know regex is not good idea I just wonder what is good one. For anyone interested here is my quick regex replace code 

    string str =" <img id=\"ctl00_RelatedLibrary_RelatedResults_ctl01_Thumb\" src=\"/script/ResearchLibrary/Logos/LibraryItemThumbnail_93_100x130.png\"";
    std::tr1::regex rx("(<img[^>]+src=\")([^\">]+)");
    std::string replacement = "$1file://newpath$2";
    std::string str2 = std::tr1::regex_replace(str, rx, replacement);

Comment: If you use a regex to update the src on images you'll eventually miss a case unless the documents you can be very confident on the consistency of their formatting.  Instead, I would try some test documents and see if base will solve your problem, and if it does, try the solution I proposed.

Comment: Obviously you'd want to set the base URL to a `file://` URL per the idea in the question. `<head><title></title></head>` is mandatory so that part should be safe.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Daniel for easy fix. When I first create the document I use about:blank for empty page then set baseurl to the directory I want to work with. I have tried to use file:// but it didn't work. Therefore I used full path name. Thanks again @Daniel and @MSalters for helping me out. For anyone interested here is the code.

```
m_Browser.Navigate( _T("about:blank") ); //navigate to blank document
IDispatch* pDispatch = m_Browser.GetHtmlDocument();

//Only if a resource or web page is loaded can we get the document
if( pDispatch != NULL )
{
    IHTMLDocument2* pHtmlDoc;
    HRESULT hr = pDispatch->QueryInterface( __uuidof( IHTMLDocument2 ), (void**)&pHtmlDoc );
    pDispatch->Release();
    if( SUCCEEDED( hr ) )
    {

// Create a safearray to store the HTML text
CComBSTR    bstrURL;
CComVariant varDummy;
SAFEARRAY      *pSA;
SAFEARRAYBOUND  saBound = {1, 0};
pSA = SafeArrayCreate(VT_VARIANT, 1, &saBound);



// Copy the HTML into the one and only element
VARIANT   *pVar;
CComBSTR   bstrHTML = "<html><head><base href=\"C:\\\"></head><body>Hello!</body></html>";              // Load the text
varDummy = bstrHTML;                        // .. into a variant

SafeArrayAccessData(pSA, (void**)&pVar);    // Access safearray data
pVar[0] = varDummy;                         // Set the text data
SafeArrayUnaccessData(pSA);                 // Release access

// Write the HTML as the document's new text
pHtmlDoc->write(pSA);                           // Overwrite HTML
SafeArrayDestroy(pSA);
pHtmlDoc->close();
    }
}
```